# GWT TextBox KeyUpHandler issue

Tags: gwt, event-handling, jsni

I am trying to check if the user has not entered anything in a `TextBox` by using the `onKeyUp` method of `KeyUpHandler` and chacking if `value.length` is 0 or not.

When I test it in a browser the condition passes  as true but when I test it in Android mobile it doesn't detect whether the `TextBox` value is 0. Please suggest. I am to new to GWT.

Code:

```
    final E12TextBox newPasswordPwd = new E12TextBox();
    newPasswordPwd.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event)
        {
            String newPass = newPasswordPwd.getText();
            if(newPass.length() != 0 && !newPass.isEmpty())
            {
                newPassImg.setStyleName("rightPass");
                confirmPasswordPwd.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
                newPassImg.setStyleName("wrongPass");
                confirmPasswordPwd.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show your code for this textbox and this handler.

Comment: final E12TextBox newPasswordPwd = new E12TextBox(); 
  newPasswordPwd.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
       String newPass = newPasswordPwd.getText();
   if(newPass.length()!= 0 && !newPass.isEmpty())
    {
                         newPassImg.setStyleName("rightPass");
          confirmPasswordPwd.setEnabled(true);
       }

    else
    {  newPassImg.setStyleName("wrongPass");
     confirmPasswordPwd.setEnabled(false);
    }
    }
  });

Comment: I need to clear the image if the text box value is 0 image like cross or tick. But it gets cleared when i test in browser but it doesn't clear when tested in android mobile . Whats the issue . Please let me know !

Comment: `.length() == 0` and `.isEmpty()` is the same thing, by the way.

Comment: Yeah but why isn't detecting when textbox value is 0 in android phones though it works proper in browser

Comment: You don't check for value to be zero, you only check for value to be empty.

Comment: Yea how to check it then so that it works in both browser and android mobile?

Comment: Please help i am badly stuck !

Comment: Did you replace getText() with getValue()? That's your first step.

Comment: ^^ What he said :) And can you post the code of your `E12TextBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getValue()` instead of `getText()`, because getText may return a null value, in which case `length()` will throw an exception.

Comment: I have used getText() to check if the user enters a text and then tries to clear off the text using backspace at that moment the image should clear immediately .

Comment: Thanks a tonn Andrei it worked getValue(). Thank you Sir ji :)